# Hawkbit all pods are showing pending

Tags: eclipse-hawkbit

I am installing `hawkbit` using helm charts,
But after installation all pods are showing pending state, its showing issue related to `pvc`.

I created `pvc` and `pv` but still same output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need for creating PVC and/or PV manually. Which version of the RabbitMQ chart are you using? I'm asking because there was a recent [version upgrade](https://github.com/eclipse/packages/pull/150/files#diff-f73ecaff8dcab70e2a8f2e0b9a3817cc6452b9e493bf208c9a03e2a2daff5da6R7).